# Pandas Date Formatting (With Optional Milliseconds)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm getting data from an API and putting it into a Pandas DataFrame. The date column needs formatting into date/time, which I am doing. However the API sometimes returns dates without milliseconds which doesn't match the format pattern. This results in an error:

```
time data '2020-07-30T15:57:37Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ' (match)
```

In this example, how can I format the date column to date/time, so all dates are formatted with milliseconds?

```
import pandas as pd

dates = {
    'date': ['2020-07-30T15:57:37Z', '2020-07-30T15:57:37.1Z']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dates)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

print(df)
```

Comment: Is your problem the error thrown when running in a datetime without mills or do you want all result to be displayed with mills?

Comment: Yes, I am thinking the easier way would be to just add .0 where the milliseconds are missing.

Answer (score 0):

do it one time with milliseconds included and another time without milliseconds included. use `errors='coerce'` to return `NaT` when `ValueError` occurs.

```py
with_miliseconds = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ',errors='coerce')
without_miliseconds = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ',errors='coerce')
```

the results would be something like this:

```
with milliseconds:
0                       NaT
1   2020-07-30 15:57:37.100
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

without milliseconds:
0   2020-07-30 15:57:37
1                   NaT
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

then you can fill `NaT`s of one dataframe with values of the other because they complement each other.

```py
with_miliseconds.fillna(without_miliseconds)
```

```
0   2020-07-30 15:57:37.000
1   2020-07-30 15:57:37.100
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

As your date string seems like the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) you can just avoid the use of the `format` param. The parser will take into account that miliseconds are optional.

```py
import pandas as pd

dates = {
    'date': ['2020-07-30T15:57:37Z', '2020-07-30T15:57:37.1Z']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dates)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

print(df)
```

```
                              date
0        2020-07-30 15:57:37+00:00
1 2020-07-30 15:57:37.100000+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a consistent format in your output DataFrame, you could run a Regex replacement before converting to a df for all values without mills.

```py
dates = {'date': [re.sub(r'Z', '.0Z', date) if '.' not in date else date for date in dates['date']]}
```

Since only those dates containing a `.` have mills, we can run the replacements on the others.
After that, everything else is the same as in your code.
Output:

```
                     date
0 2020-07-30 15:57:37.000
1 2020-07-30 15:57:37.100
```