# How to deal with inconsistent date series in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

[Inconsistent date formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCuzj.png)

As shown in the photo above, the check-in and check-out dates are inconsistent. Whenever I try to clean convert the entire series to datetime using `df['Check-in date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Check-in date'], errors='coerce')` and
`df['Check-out date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Check-out date'], errors='coerce')` the days and months get mixed up. I don't really know what to do now. I also tried splitting the days months and years and re-arranging them, but I still have no luck.

My goal here is to get the total night stay of our guest but due to the inconsistency, I end up getting negative total night stays.

I'd appreciate any help here. Thanks!

Comment: what data type they are? 
I guess, strings (objects), - so simple extract the date part into the new column  replace "-" with "/" and convert it to datetime

Answer (score 1):

You can try different formats with [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) and return a DateTime object if any of them works.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def try_different_formats(value):
  only_date_format = "%d/%m/%Y"
  date_and_time_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  try:
    return datetime.strptime(value,only_date_format)
  except ValueError:
    pass
  
  try:
    return datetime.strptime(value,date_and_time_format)
  except ValueError:
    return pd.NaT
```

in your example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Check-in date': ['19/02/2022','2022-02-12 00:00:00']})
```

```
         Check-in date
0           19/02/2022
1  2022-02-12 00:00:00
```

[`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) method will run this function on every value of the `Check-in date`
column. the result would be a column of DateTime objects.

```py
df['Check-in date'].apply(try_different_formats)
```

```
0   2022-02-19
1   2022-02-12
Name: Check-in date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

for a more pandas-specific solution you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72728287/10462931).